# AWS Elastic Load Balancer selectively enable SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elb

I currently have a rails-based web app that requires a small subset of pages to be served over HTTP - but prefer to serve the rest over HTTPS. In my current AWS setup, SSL terminates at the elastic load balancer and all communication with my app servers is over HTTP. Because of this, solutions like [Rack SSL Enforcer](https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer) aren't appropriate. Currently, I'm serving the following JS snippet in each page to handle the redirect:

```
<% if should_be_ssl? %>
<script>
  if (window.location.protocol != "https:"){
    window.location.href = "https:" + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
  }
</script>
<% else %>
<script>
if (window.location.protocol != "http:"){
  window.location.href = "http:" + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
}
</script>
<% end %>
```

This results in a relatively significant performance hit each time one of these pages is accessed. Does anyone know of a way to selectively serve certain pages over SSL and control this at the load balancer level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't currently supported in the ELB itself, however the ELBs provide an `X-Forwarded-Proto` header. You can check this to see whether the request from the client was over HTTPS. You can then serve a redirect response rather than the page content if necessary. See [this blog post](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/keeping-customers-happy-another-new-elastic-load-balancer-feature/) from the AWS guys for more information.

You'll have to implement this logic either

1. with middleware, e.g rack-ssl-enforcer

   Looking at the documentation for [rack ssl enforcer](https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer), 
   it appears to support the `X-Forwarded-Proto` out of the box, 
   so you may not need to do anything at all. You can see in 
   [the source](https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer/blob/6b2d1ca2bfcd74090cd85c7101257db17f92cc58/lib/rack/ssl-enforcer.rb#L122) that the header is respected.
2. in your application (probably with a redirect response 
   rather than on the client)
3. in a reverse proxy, e.g. an haproxy between your app server and the ELB

   ```
   acl is_http hdr(X-Forwarded-Proto) http
   acl account_login url_beg /account/login
   redirect scheme https code 301 if account_login is_http
   ```

Depending on your configuration, if you have any other reverse proxies between the ELB and whatever's checking the header, you may need to configure those to pass the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header correctly. See [this issue](https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer/issues/26), for instance.

Comment: Thanks, Joe! I'll check this out today and let you know if this is working for me.

Comment: Hey, @DanL. How did it go? Was rack-ssl-enforcer up to the task?